# how to remove axis label while keeping ticklabel and tick in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to remove axis label with keeping tick, ticklabel.

This is `seaborn heatmap` example.

In this case, I'd like to remove only yaixs label('month') and xaxis label('year') label.

I tried to use follows but I couldn't remove only labels.

```
ax.xaxis.set_visible(False) 
ax.set_xticklabels([]) 
ax.set_xticks([])
```

[image]

Codes is follow.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

flights = sns.load_dataset("flights")
flights = flights.pivot("month", "year", "passengers")
ax = sns.heatmap(flights)


#ax.xaxis.set_visible(False) # remove axis label & xtick label 
#ax.set_xticklabels([]) # remove xtick label 
#ax.set_xticks([]) # remove xtick label & tick

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ax.set_xlabel('')
ax.set_ylabel('')
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do, even if it is a workaround, it is to just set empty labels:

```
ax.set_xlabel("")
ax.set_ylabel("")
```